# Grab displaymember from a combobox and use to fill a textbox

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a combobox that is being filled by a dataadapter. I have no problems filling the combobox at all, but I am trying to figure out how to grab the displaymember and not the selected value.

```
cotcommand = new SqlCommand();
                cotguestadapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                cotcommand.Connection = cottageconnect;
                cotcommand.CommandText = "SELECT Phone, (\"Last Name\" + ', ' + \"First Name\") AS NAME FROM Guests ORDER BY NAME";
                cotguestadapter.SelectCommand = cotcommand;
                cotguestadapter.Fill(cotguestdataset);
                cboGuests.DataSource = cotguestdataset.Tables[0];
                cboGuests.DisplayMember = "NAME";
                cboGuests.ValueMember = "Phone";
```

I can easily get the valuemember and do what I want with it, but I would really like to pull the displaymember (which is the concatenated name) and display that in a textbox. I need the display name for a confirmation box that the user can select yes and then my code will insert the registration in to the database at that time.

Can I get the displaymember from the combobox and use it in a textbox?

Comment: Nothing like putting SQL stuff as strings in the code behind the UI. reminds me or "good ol' VB6 days".

Comment: Yeah...I have an old teacher ;)   Any help with my question though?

Comment: Yes, don't try to "read data" from the UI. UI is not data, not even in winforms. Just grab the data item from whatever `IEnumerable` you're getting it to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DisplayMember` **in this case** is in fact the column name, so you can just extract the underlying data bound item and get the value:

```
var someDisplay = ((DataRowView) someItem).Row[comboBox1.DisplayMember];
//someDisplay is still an object, just cast or convert to what you want.
```

Comment: After the DataRowView you have a "someItem"   Is that item meant to be the table that this is pulled from? I tried putting in NAME as that was the name of the column and that doesn't seem to be working.

I tried:
string someDisplay = ((DataRowView) NAME).Row[cboGuests.DisplayMember];

Comment: @user2966944 `someItem` here is some item of your `comboBox1`, for example `comboBox1.Items[0]`, you can also make some loop through your `comboBox1.Items` and pass in each item as the same role with `someItem` in my code and get the DisplayMember as what you want.

Comment: aaahhh...I see now!  Thank you sir.  That did what I want it to do for the most part.  Now I just need to figure out how to get the right row number. I can select the 5th person down in the combobox, but it will still display the first row person and not the person in the 5th row from the database.  If that makes sense.  For example:  If I picked the 5th name, then I would want it to be comboBox1.Items[4]

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to do this...I do appreciate it. I am going to keep working with this instead of simply using the original valuemember as part of another SQL query to grab the name again as I was originally planning on doing.

Comment: @Marty to get the selected item, you just need to access the property `comboBox1.SelectedItem`, you can also handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to run your code right when it's changed, also remember to check for the `SelectedIndex` not being `-1` (which frequently happens when dealing with ComboBox).

Comment: I had just started to use the comboBox1.SelectedItem and found that it worked and I was going to come back here and make another comment, but you are on top of it and beat me to it.  Thanks again King King.